# setting cookie at domain level in React with js-cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, js-cookie

I have a React application. Currently I am using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to manage my cookies. Right now I am facing this problem: I need the cookies to be available at domain level and not subdomain level.

Eg: my site is running under mysite.mydomain.com, then I need the cookies to be available to any site that is running under .mydomain

I read in other post that I can be achievable just setting the path to "/". SO I mad this:

```
Cookies.set('session', myvalue ,{path:'/'});
```

However it's still creating the cookie at `mysite.mydomain.com`

So, what else can I do? I dont want to writte the domain directly when I create the cookie due that it's not clean and also the development is under localhost and it would get a mess. So, I am looking for a clean solution

Thank you very much

Comment: @mplungjan yes, am sure, I check it many times loooking for a reason but nothing. Doesnt have to be something with the 'domain' attribute? or with 'path' is enough?

Comment: RTM: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#domain

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `domain`

```
Cookies.set('session', myvalue ,{ domain: 'mydomain.com' });
```

[More info](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#domain).

This should work according to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie). In case it doesn't [try setting a dot in the beginning `.mydomain.com`](https://developers.livechatinc.com/blog/setting-cookies-to-subdomains-in-javascript/).